# Matplotlib ginput causes image to not appear

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to use [`matlabplot.pyplot.ginput`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.ginput.html) in a Jupyter notebook to select points on an image, however calling `ginput` causes the image to not appear. Instead, it hangs as if the cell is still running but no picture appears. If I omit the call to `ginput`, I see the image displayed just fine.

[image: hanging execution]

Interestingly, if I interrupt the kernel, the image *does* appear (although I can't interact with it) and I get a stack trace (pasted below):

[image: interrupted kernel]

My code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

source_img = cv2.imread('foo.jpg')

def specify_points(img):
    fig = plt.figure()
    fig.set_label('Select corresponding points in the image')
    plt.imshow(cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))
    plt.axis('off')
    return plt.ginput(1)

%matplotlib notebook
source_points = specify_points(source_img)
```

Stack trace when the kernel is interrupted:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyboardInterrupt                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-8652456a3eae> in <module>
      1 # Select corresponding points on the images
      2 get_ipython().run_line_magic('matplotlib', 'notebook')
----> 3 source_points = specify_points(source_img)

<ipython-input-3-b99a0d1655ce> in specify_points(img)
      9     plt.imshow(cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))
     10     plt.axis('off')
---> 11     return plt.ginput(1)

~/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py in ginput(*args, **kwargs)
    735     If *timeout* is negative, does not timeout.
    736     """
--> 737     return gcf().ginput(*args, **kwargs)
    738 
    739 

~/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/matplotlib/figure.py in ginput(self, n, timeout, show_clicks, mouse_add, mouse_pop, mouse_stop)
   2307                                                   mouse_stop=mouse_stop)
   2308         return blocking_mouse_input(n=n, timeout=timeout,
-> 2309                                     show_clicks=show_clicks)
   2310 
   2311     def waitforbuttonpress(self, timeout=-1):

~/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/matplotlib/blocking_input.py in __call__(self, n, timeout, show_clicks)
    261         self.clicks = []
    262         self.marks = []
--> 263         BlockingInput.__call__(self, n=n, timeout=timeout)
    264         return self.clicks
    265 

~/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/matplotlib/blocking_input.py in __call__(self, n, timeout)
     90         try:
     91             # Start event loop.
---> 92             self.fig.canvas.start_event_loop(timeout=timeout)
     93         finally:  # Run even on exception like ctrl-c.
     94             # Disconnect the callbacks.

~/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/matplotlib/backend_bases.py in start_event_loop(self, timeout)
   2265         while self._looping and counter * timestep < timeout:
   2266             self.flush_events()
-> 2267             time.sleep(timestep)
   2268             counter += 1
   2269 

KeyboardInterrupt:
```

This seemed like a cleaner approach than using events and `mpl_connect`, but so far I'm not having any luck.

I'm using:

- macOS Catalina 10.15.4
- Jupyter Notebook with Python 3.7.3 64-bit
- Matplotlib 3.1.2